# How can i redirect all from localhost/ to localhost/mvc/index.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current .htaccess setting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mvc
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Can you provide a few example URLs and how you expect them to be rewritten? Do you want to redirect image/js requests?

Comment: I want that request localhost/something is redirecting to localhost/mvc/index.php...

Comment: are the URL parameters supposed to be discarded?

Comment: at that moment,yes! but it would be cool if you explain both decisions)

Comment: You should edit your question and state what you want to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: File index.php is located in htdocs/mvc/index.php, therefore it available with request localhost/mvc/index.php but i want that it would be available by that request localhost/index.php